# MariaDB Select Min-Date (earliest) from multiple columns

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, mindate

I need to do a select within a MariaDB, where I have one row per customer and the earliest date out of three different tables with action datetime values.

Example Tables:

**Main Table**

| customer-id | Column_X |
| --- | --- |
| First | Things |
| Second | Things |

**Table One**

| customer-id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| First | Date |
| Second | Date |

**Table Two**

| customer-id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| First | Date |
| Second | Earliest Date (Table2) |

**Table Three**

| customer-id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| First | Earliest Date (Table3) |
| Second | Date |

My aim is to have the earliest date out of the three columns in the other tables in one column within the select.

What I tried to do is this:

```sql
SELECT main.customer-id , main.Column_X 
    (SELECT LEAST(C) FROM (VALUES ((table1.date) , (table2.date), (table3.date)) AS C) AS First_Action
FROM main_table main
LEFT JOIN table_one table1 ON table1.cutomer-id = main.customer-id
LEFT JOIN table_two table2 ON table2.cutomer-id = main.customer-id
LEFT JOIN table_three table3 ON table3.cutomer-id = main.customer-id
GROUP BY main.customer-id;
```

Unfortunatly, I don't get any results just an error message.

So the resulting table should look something like this:

**Result**

| customer-id | Column_X | First_Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Things | Earliest Date (Table 3) |
| Second | Things | Earliest Date (Table 2) |

I just started working with SQL statments and therefore have basically no experience. Help would be much appreciated!

Many Greetings
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply need a LEAST function -

```
SELECT main.customer-id , main.Column_X,
       LEAST(table1.date, table2.date, table3.date) AS First_Action
  FROM main_table main
  LEFT JOIN table_one table1 ON table1.cutomer-id = main.customer-id
  LEFT JOIN table_two table2 ON table2.cutomer-id = main.customer-id
  LEFT JOIN table_three table3 ON table3.cutomer-id = main.customer-id;
```